# Transfer a SQLServer table directly to DuckDB in R

Tags: r, duckdb

I've been reading into DuckDB recently and most of the examples involve having some sort of data already in an R session, then pushing that data into DuckDB.

Here is a basic example of that using the iris dataset;

```
library("DBI")
con = dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "iris_table", iris)
dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT "Species", MIN("Sepal.Width") FROM iris_table GROUP BY "Species"')
```

Let's say I have data in a sql server table and want to directly write that data into a duck db.

Is there a way to do this?

if I had a sql query

```
' SELECT * FROM iris_table "
```

and wanted to read that directly into DuckDB, how would that work?
I haven't seen any examples of this online

1. How would that work?
2. Would this even be a smart or desirable approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to export from SQL Server to Parquet files and then directly query those or import in DuckDB.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this approach

- Within R, import data from SQL Server into an R dataframe
- Within R, export the data from the R dataframe to DuckDB

Answer (score 1):

In Duckdb you can use as in memory database so there is no direct access to sql database server currently but what you can do is that

first

load the data from sql server into pandas dataframe using Pyodbc and then read the data  from the pandas dataframe

```
pip install pyodbc 
pip install duckdb
pip install pandas

import pyodbc
import pasndas as pd
import duckdb
SERVER = '<server-address>'
DATABASE = '<database-name>'
USERNAME = '<username>'
PASSWORD = '<password>'

cnx = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(cnx)
SQL_QUERY = """
SELECT 
*
FROM 
Sales;
"""
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(SQL_QUERY)

records = cursor.fetchall()
```

After you pull the date from SQL SERVER  then load into Pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.Dataframe.from_records(records)
```

then read the data from pandas dataframe

```
 duckdb.sql('SELECT * FROM df').fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an ODBC connection to a duckdb. Then export required data from the SQL aerver to thr duckdb. See more from https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/api/odbc/overview